# Json Parsing Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am creating a simple Login page. In my project I want to parse the json string. But it gives me following error.

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 
\"Valid fragment, but not JSON\" 
UserInfo=0xa6e70a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Valid fragment, but not JSON}"
```

In my code if I am putting another json string than it is working. And also my original json string is giving me the data in browser. So what to do?

My Code is:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.bevbucks.com/gbs/api.json/token?user=rverma@prismetric.com&pwd=verma!pris"]];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
//getting the data
NSData *newData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
//json parse

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"type :  %@", jsonObject  );
```

Comment: Please put the JSON, and your code...

Comment: @V.J. Please check my code...

Comment: This return "60ee094456b6fc03f386af50c443b471" and it's a wrong JSON formate...

Comment: and this webservice contains your credentials. So any one can use your  account from the dev.bevbucks.com. and also this account will be misused. So Please change your credentials....

Comment: @V.J. So it means we can not work on string ? i mean if we got the response in json in string then how its not secure ?

Comment: the json format should be

{"yourKey":"60ee094456b6fc03f386af50c443b471"}
{"60ee094456b6fc03f386af50c443b471"}
["60ee094456b6fc03f386af50c443b471"]

Answer (score 2):

The returned string:

```
"60ee094456b6fc03f386af50c443b471"
```

Isn't valid JSON, and should at least be:

```
[ "60ee094456b6fc03f386af50c443b471" ]
```

So there is a bug in the server, and not your code.  If you cannot get this bug fixed then you're going to have to workaround it.

From [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>     realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most
>     languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Comment: @Sam you think you've solved it?  Actually I don't think my answer is correct and I believe the issue is with the lack of "Accept-Encoding" HTTP Request header...

Comment: @Sam I've just retried using *Postman* and get the same response with and without `Accept: application/json` set, so it looks like I might be right.